# Passing variable from JavaScript to PHP using AJAX doesn't show anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to send a PHP variable to JavaScript using AJAX and implementing to HTML, but the result doesn't show anything.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="contain" id="konten_data"
     style="margin-top: 20px;"></div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
function tampilDepan(id){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'userAction.php',
                data: 'action_type=tdepan&id='+id,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#konten_data').html(html);
                }
            });
        }
```

My PHP code (userAction.php):

```
($_POST['action_type'] == 'tdepan'){
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "universitas");

$datas = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM mahasiswa where user='john' ");
        if(!empty($datas)){
            while ($datak = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datas)){
                echo  '<div class="row" style="margin-left: -90px;">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"
                     src="images/test/'.$datak['gmb_batik'].'" alt=""></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                <div class="content-box-large">
                <p>'.$datak['desc_batik'].'</p>
                </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-left: -90px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="content-box-large">
                        <h1 >asal <strong>'.$datak['asal_batik'].'</strong></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-16 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"
                      src="login/admin/files/qrcode/'.$datak['qr_batik'].'"
                      alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-left: -90px; margin-top: 10px;">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-9 col-md-offset-4">
                    <div class="content-box-large">
                    <p>'.$datak['pola_batik'].' </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>';
            }
        }else {``
            echo '<tr><td colspan="5">No user(s) found......</td></tr>';
        }`
}
```

I don't know what is wrong, I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: are the backticks in the else part of the code actually in your code?

Comment: Go to your browsers developer tools network tab - check what the request is, and what the status and response are - while you're there, check the developer tools console for any errors

Comment: Can you share network result from console? Btw - remove ` after else.

Comment: @RST yes, inside my code.

Comment: @Jaromanda X ok sir.

Comment: For starters remove the backticks

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the javascript code to

```
function tampilDepan(id){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'userAction.php',
                data: {action_type: "tdepan", id: id},
                success:function(html){
                    $('#konten_data').html(html);
                }
            });
    }
```

As you can see, data is passed as an object instead of a string.

Also, be aware that if no user was found, you are putting a `<tr>` inside a `<div>`.

Comment: thank you for your awareness sir, and i was changed my code, but nothing happen

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: yes, i did sir <script src="js/jquery.1.7.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Do you see in the network tab if you either get a script error or that the ajax call is never made?

Comment: i dont see script error and ajax call on the tab sir

Comment: If you do not see the ajax call in the network tab, then your webpage is not doing one. What will run the function tamilDepan? Maybe the rest of the code could be included in the posting?

Comment: for calling function on php, i just use that javascript sir. i use another javascript code but for calling another function sir, like slideshow

Comment: Then nothing calls the function tampilDepan and it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

try to change in your ajax call.
`function tampilDepan(id){
            var postData ={"action_type":tdepan,"id":id};
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'userAction.php',
                data: postData ,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#konten_data').html(html);
                }
            });
    }`

Comment: thankyou for your help sir, and i was changed my code sir, but nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

try to use the format below in calling ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    data:  '{ "action_type":"' + tdepan + '", "id":"' + id + '"}',
    url: 'userAction.php',
    success: function (data) {
        conosle.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to get your data using `konten_data` probably by using jQuery selector `$('#konten_data').val();`
, but I don't see it in the PHP code as where you are pushing the data to render onto the DOM. Try setting the value of `konten_data` by adding an element before the success callback or on DOM render and you should be good from there.

Comment: this looks more like a comment than an answer.

Comment: @RST - looks more like someone didn't read the question very well

Comment: @HydroNyx - why would the PHP require an element with ID=konten_data when one already exists in the HTML?

Comment: Ah my bad, I thought it was other way around. Reading from Php to Ajax.

Question itself is misleading in heading and the description

`passing variable from javascript to php using ajax doesnt how anything`
vs 
`im trying to send variable php to javascrip using ajax`